# AIR, load image stored locally

Tags: flash, air

I package an IPA file including some assets (images). Once installed, I want to load an image in my swf: which is the path of this image? How can I load it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you packaged your assets folder, the installation should contain its contents in the `File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("./assets/")` folder.

You can reference the image file by `File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("./assets/myImage.png")`

To read the file to a byteArray,

```
var f:File=File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("./assets/myImage.png");
var fs:FileStream=new FileStream();
var ba:ByteArray=new ByteArray();

fs.open(f, FileMode.READ);
fs.readBytes(ba);
//unsure about this, also try CompressionAlgorithm.DEFLATE
ba.uncompress(CompressionAlgorithm.ZLIB); //uncompresses the byteArray
fs.close();
```

You will now have the bytes of the image file in the byteArray.

Comment: Finally, I loaded the image using regular URLRequest("asset/"+fileToLoad). Is there any performance improvement with ByteArray?

Comment: I haven't tried, but if you are using just 1, I don't think there should be any **significant** performance improvement